# How to truncate table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In `CakePHP3`, how to truncate table?

`$this->Model->query('TRUNCATE TABLE table_name_in_mysql;')` is used in `CakePHP 1.3`. I want to know its replacement in `CakePHP 3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [cackephp-3-raw-sql-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312583/cakephp-3-raw-sql-query%22%22)

Comment: Thanks, for the link :)

Comment: While raw sql would work, there is a [truncateSql()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Schema.Table.html#_truncateSql) function in CakePHP 3.