# sql query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I created a cakephp project and I'm a beginner on php development . I have an sql query that I couldn't execute it on cake cause it's really complicated.

my query is :

```
select * from schedules as s left join flight_plans as f on s.flight_plan_id = f.id 
left join drones as d on d.id = s.drone_ref 
where 
d.uid = "xxx" and 
is_approved = 1 and
is_confirmed = 1 and
is_finalized = 1 and
DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') and 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s')  >=  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(start_timestamp,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , '%H:%i:%s')and DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s') <= DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, '%H:%i:%s') and ((
s.type = 0 and
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') and s.end_timestamp)
or (
s.end_timestamp IS NULL and 
s.type = 1 and
(DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.monday or 
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.tuesday or 
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.wednesday or 
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.thursday or 
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.friday or 
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.saturday or 
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.sunday )))
order by DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, '%H:%i:%s') , s.type
```

I tried like 2 ways

the first :

```
$uid = $this->request->data['uid'];
        $options['joins'] = array(
                                array('table' => 'Drones',
                                    'alias' => 'd',
                                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                    'Drones.id = Schedules.drone_ref',
                                    )
                             ),
                                array('table' => 'FlightPlans',
                                    'alias' => 'f',
                                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                    'FlightPlans.id = Schedules.flight_plan_id',
                                    )
                             )
        );
        $options['conditions'] = array(
                        'AND' => array(
                                    array('Schedules.drone_ref' => $uid),
                                    array('Schedules.is_approved' => 1),
                                    array('Schedules.is_confirmed' => 1),
                                    array('Schedules.is_finalized' => 1),
                                    array('DATE_FORMAT(Schedules.start_timestamp, \'%Y-%m-%d\') <= ' => 'DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%Y-%m-%d\')'),
                                    array('DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%H:%i:%s\') >=' => 'DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(Schedules.start_timestamp,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , \'%H:%i:%s\')'),
                                    array('DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%H:%i:%s\') <=' => 'DATE_FORMAT(Schedules.start_timestamp, \'%H:%i:%s\')')
                        ),
                        'AND' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'OR' => array(
                                            'AND' => array(
                                                    array('Schedules.type' => 0),
                                                    array('DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%Y-%m-%d\') <=' => 'DATE_FORMAT(Schedules.end_timestamp, \'%Y-%m-%d\')')
                                                    ),
                                            'AND' => array(
                                                    array('Schedules.type' => 1),
                                                    array('Schedules.end_timestamp' => null),
                                                        'OR' => array(
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.monday'),
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.tuesday'),
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.wednesday'),
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.thursday'),
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.friday'),
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.saturday'),
                                                                    array('DAYOFWEEK(NOW())' => 'Schedules.sunday')
                                                                    )
                                                    )
                                            )
                                     )
        ));
        $results = $this->Schedules->find('all', $options);
```

and the second :

```
$results = $connection->execute('select * from schedules as s left join flight_plans as f on s.flight_plan_id = f.id left join drones as d on d.id = s.drone_ref
where d.uid = "xxx" and is_approved = 1 and is_confirmed = 1 and is_finalized = 1 and
DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, \'%Y-%m-%d\') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%Y-%m-%d\') and
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%H:%i:%s\')  >=  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(start_timestamp,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , \'%H:%i:%s\')and DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%H:%i:%s\') <= DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, \'%H:%i:%s\') and ((
s.type = 0 and
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), \'%Y-%m-%d\') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, \'%Y-%m-%d\') and s.end_timestamp)
or (
s.end_timestamp IS NULL and
s.type = 1 and
(DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.monday or
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.tuesday or
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.wednesday or
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.thursday or
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.friday or
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.saturday or
DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = s.sunday )))
order by DATE_FORMAT(s.start_timestamp, \'%H:%i:%s\') , s.type')->fetchAll('assoc');
```

both of them return null value , while when I run the same sql query in phpmy admin I got other result !!!

any help ?!

Answer (score 0):

it's hasMany belongsTo table.

you may refer to its documentations

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

and if you prefer CakePHP 3 Raw SQL Query, this previous topic might help:

[CakePHP 3 Raw SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312583/cakephp-3-raw-sql-query)

Comment: I tried 2 queries but still didn't work . please check my answer's update !